# Is the Intel graphics driver separate from the NVidia driver?

Tags: release-loki, graphics

I have NVidia driver 375.66.  I can go to `nvidia-settings` > PRIME profiles > Select GPU > Intel (Power Saving Mode).  Logout to confirm the switch.  When I do this my machine becomes extremely unstable.  The entire OS freezes constantly.  I switch back to Nvidia (performance mode) and the system runs fine.

Arch-Linux says I have several [options](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_15_9560):  Open source driver, a proprietary driver with bumblebee, or Proprietary driver with PRIME output offloading.  I don't know which is best for me.  My goal is to save power by switching to the integrated graphics when I'm on battery (so the open-source driver is out the question because of power consumption issues, see arch Linux link).  I want to keep the option to use the more powerful 1050 GPU.

Can I upgrade the Intel driver without impacting the Nvidia driver?

System:  Intel HD Graphics on Dell XPS 15 9560 (2017 model).

Comment: first I'd suggest upgrading the driver to Nvidia 381. it works better for me (xps 9560)

Answer (score 1):

first I'd suggest upgrading the driver to Nvidia 381. it works better for me (xps 9560).

when I'm running in Nvidia driver the Intel HD card behaves perfectly.
 I usually switch Nvidia card off and use Intel HD solely, unless I'm goin to play games. didn't see much difference in battery life though, it still suck